# Group generators and normalization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $N \leq G$ a finite subgroup, and suppose $N = \langle S \rangle$. I need to prove that $g\langle S \rangle g^{-1}=\langle gSg^{-1}\rangle$.

I'm not sure what to do with inverses, ie. if I have $gs_1g^{-1}\cdot (gsg^{-1})^{-1}$ how to prove it is from $g \langle S \rangle g^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in \langle S \rangle$.
Then $x=s_1^{n_1}\dots s_k^{n_k}$ where $s_i\in S,k\in\Bbb{N}$ and $n_i\in\{1,-1\}$
Thus $gxg^{-1}=gs_1^{n_1}\dots s_k^{n_k}g^{-1}=(gs_1g^{-1})^{n_1}\dots (gs_kg^{-1})^{n_k}\in\langle gSg^{-1}\rangle$.
We conclude that $\langle S \rangle\subseteq \langle gSg^{-1}\rangle$.
The reverse inclusion can be done in the similar way.